# How to get notified about change in Cosmos DB through ChangeFeed?

Tags: azure, design-patterns, azure-cosmosdb

When I'm browsing through [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) all I can see is "observing" changes on ChangeFeed. Even the first diagram there shows only direction **from** external services (Storm, Azure Functions, etc.) **towards** ChangeFeed.

Is there any pattern that (is not obvious for me) we can use for getting notified about changes in Cosmos DB over ChangeFeed?
Or there really needs to be support built-in e.g. Azure Functions to get this "PUSH" scenario working?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Agree, something similar to what Aws does with DynamoDb streams (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/).
I'm trying to find out how I can get notified when a document is deleted via TTL, but found the documentation around Change Feeds and TTL is very limited/poor.

Comment: I ended up with completely different strategy and won't use ChangeFeed. Maybe later, when e.g. Azure Functions gets support for that, ChangeFeed will be interesting topic again.

Comment: I agree, the documentation on that link is not clear. Took me several reads to comprehend it too as I'm after the same functionality but on Tables not documents. However my interpretation is different, I think it does do what you want. I think the arrows on the diagrams are bogus, check the code snippets for the logic of the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Azure Cosmos DB Change Feed processor library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#change-feed-processor) was released recently in order to make listening to the Azure Cosmos DB change feed a bit easier. It handles automatic lease management for a set of change feed listening "workers" to read across Cosmos DB partitions; enabling you to easily scale out the set of change feed listening workers. Using this, you can build a pub/sub model on top of the consumer of the library.

With that said, integration between Azure Cosmos DB's change feed + Azure Functions is on the Azure Cosmos DB roadmap (as of current date - 8/5/17) to help make pushing changes even easier to accomplish. No specific dates have been announced for this yet; but do stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to provide some updates to this question since the Azure Functions support has been added by now and the Change Feed Processor library has been fully integrated in the Azure SQL SDK for Java/.NET.

It is really easy to get notifications from a Change Feed, without using Azure Functions, through the usage of the [ChangeFeedProcessor API](https://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-java/3.0.0/com/azure/data/cosmos/ChangeFeedProcessor.html) - but bear in mind, it is not really a "*PUSH*" scenario as the Change Feed is queried in a polling fashion by the client!

The code would look like this:

```
public static void startChangeFeedProcessor(String hostName, CosmosContainer feedContainer, CosmosContainer leaseContainer) {
  ChangeFeedProcessor.Builder()
    .hostName(hostName)
    .feedContainer(feedContainer)
    .leaseContainer(leaseContainer)
    .options(new ChangeFeedProcessorOptions().leasePrefix("my-lease-prefix")) //not required
    .handleChanges(docs -> {
        for (CosmosItemProperties document : docs) {
            System.out.println("Read document from Change Feed: " + document.toJson(SerializationFormattingPolicy.INDENTED));
        }
    })
    .build()
    .start()
    .subscribe();
}
```

You can check out [more in-depth details about the Azure CosmosDB Change Feed here](https://medium.com/@domenicosibilio/azure-cosmos-db-change-feed-a-zero-downtime-data-migration-story-99c4521f7159).